# How does Dart Set<E> compare items?

Tags: flutter, dart, set, comparison

I just stuffed a bunch of `MyClass` inside a `Set` in Dart. `MyClass` does not implement `Comparable`, and does not have an `==` operator defined. It compiled fine.

For this `Set` to detect duplicates properly, do I have to implement `Comparable` interface, or just override the `==` operator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All Dart classes derive from `Object`, which does provide `operator ==` and `hashCode`.  `Object`'s default implementations check for object *identity*; an instance of your class will compare equal only to itself.

If you want two different instances to be able to compare equal, then you need to:

- Implement `operator ==` and `hashCode` in your custom class. `Set`'s default implementation is a `LinkedHashSet`, which does not use `Comparable`. (There is a [`SplayTreeSet` implementation](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.4/dart-collection/SplayTreeSet-class.html) that does use `Comparable`, however, but lookup and insertions would be O(log n) instead of O(1).)
- Alternatively use the [`LinkedHashSet` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashSet/LinkedHashSet.html) or the [`HashSet` constructor](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/HashSet/HashSet.html) and pass appropriate callbacks for equality and hash code computations.