# How to Delete duplicate items from a List Dart | Flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web

I have a set of items. From this i want to delete all duplicate values. i tried this
`finalList = [...{...users!}];` and this `print(users.toSet().toList());`. But both are printing all the data in the list. It didn't removing duplicate values. Below is my list

```
List users = [
    {
      "userEmail":"tintu@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userEmail":"john@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userEmail":"tintu@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userEmail":"rose@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userEmail":"john@gmail.com"
    },
  ];
```

Expected Output

```
List users = [
    {
      "userEmail":"tintu@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userEmail":"john@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      "userEmail":"rose@gmail.com"
    },
  ];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try, here you get the unique list

```
void main() {
  var users = [
    {"userEmail": "tintu@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "john@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "tintu@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "rose@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "john@gmail.com"},
  ];
  var uniqueList = users.map((o) => o["userEmail"]).toSet();
  print(uniqueList.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your attempts don't work because most objects (including `Map`) use the default implementation for the `==` operator, which checks only for object identity.  See: [How does a set determine that two objects are equal in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29567322/) and [How does Dart Set compare items?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62867472/).

One way to make the `List` to `Set` to `List` approach work is by explicitly specifying how the `Set` should compare objects:

```
import 'dart:collection';

void main() {
  var users = [
    {"userEmail": "tintu@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "john@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "tintu@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "rose@gmail.com"},
    {"userEmail": "john@gmail.com"},
  ];

  var finalList = [
    ...LinkedHashSet<Map<String, String>>(
      equals: (user1, user2) => user1['userEmail'] == user2['userEmail'],
      hashCode: (user) => user['userEmail'].hashCode,
    )..addAll(users)
  ];
  finalList.forEach(print);
}
```

Comment: It giving error Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable<Map<String, String>>'

Comment: @MukSystem That's because your original `List` is a `List<dynamic>`.  Fix that (as I did in the code above).